# Unknown Hostname in Java Socket Programming

Tags: java, android, sockets, serversocket

I have five domain server and i want to connect to that server using java socket programming in my android application.

Here my servers 
    "ANY1.g%%%%%%%%.dk"
    "ANY2.g%%%%%%%%.dk"
    "ANY3.g%%%%%%%%.dk"
    "ANY4.g%%%%%%%%.dk"
    "ANY5.g%%%%%%%%.dk"

So when I ping to any of server via ping command in run prompt, it is working perfect and getting response.

but when i am trying to crate socket using this server it gives me "Unknown Host" error.

Here is my code:

```
try
{
    hostname = "ANY SERVER DOMAIN NAME";
    port = ANY;
    socket = new Socket(hostname, port);
    socket.setReceiveBufferSize(2048);
    socket.setKeepAlive(true);
    Log.e("SOCKET",socket.isConnected());
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    Log.e("ERROR",e.getMessage());
}
```

Is there any problem with code or any suggestion will be accepted?

Menifest file :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.siliconithub.android.greencall"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />

<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_app_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".GreenCall"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_green_call"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".RecentCallActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_recentcall"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".RecentCallDetailActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_recentcall_detail"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".FavouritesActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_fovourites"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ContactsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_contacts"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ContactDetailsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_contactdetails"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".TelnetServerActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_telnetserver"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SettingActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_setting"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SearchContactsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_search_contacts"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>

    <service
        android:name=".UpdateStatusService"
        android:label="@string/title_service_update_status"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_app_icon"
        android:enabled="true" />

    <receiver android:name=".PhoneStateBroadcastReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
</manifest>
```

thank you.

Comment: did you added `android.permission.INTERNET` to the manifest?

Comment: yes internet permission is already given in android menifest file.

Comment: Do you know the ip address of **Frontend1.greencall.dk**?

Comment: Then try `socket = new Socket("195.190.30.135", 443);` and let me know what happen..

Comment: Actually your code works fine in my case..

Comment: @user370305 The hostname should be fine, I just tested it. I guess his permissions are broken.

Comment: I have no problem with that code, I've just tested it, you may have some dns problems, try the ip as suggested instead

Comment: @brimborium - Yes, I know even OP's code runs fine in my system..

Comment: but i can make socket using other domain "greencall.nu" but not using among above of them. Also i can see you my menifest also.

Comment: What is different about that server / dns? 
Have you tried logging in from a different network service provider / Wifi source?
I have the same problem - but only on certain wifi networks - maybe you do too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import java.net.Socket;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Socket socket = new Socket("%%%%.%%%%%.dk", PORT NUMBER);
            socket.setReceiveBufferSize(2048);
            socket.setKeepAlive(true);
            System.out.println("socket " + socket.isConnected());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("error " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

This returns

```
socket true
```

In Java (no Android). It also works in Android (sherpya has tested it - see his comment below). I guess there is something wrong with your permissions. Can you show us your manifest?

Comment: @sherpya Thanks for testing that.

Comment: if i am using the ip address of it then it is creating socket. and if i ma using hostname then it is not. Also all above domains have same ip address "195.190.30.135". So it may be the problem.

Comment: As sherpya suggested, there might be something wrong with your dns. If your servers are supporting some HTTP GET, you can try if you are able to get that message over the standard Android internet browser to see if that is working.

Comment: ok...thanks for your help. i will get it through the internet browser. I also think that there might something wrong with dns.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use an `InetAddress`+ `SocketAddress` to resolve the host, then connect to it using a socket. 
Try:

```
InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName("ANY1.g%%%%%%%.dk");
SocketAddress sockaddr = new InetSocketAddress(addr, 443);
socket = new Socket();
socket.connect(sockaddr, timeoutint)
```

Comment: i have tried this code also but it is working for the other dns but not for that i have listed.